# Which CMS for a mobile app? No HTML, just XML or JSON

Tags: xml, cms, web-services, json

I am a newbie in content management systems. I would need a CMS that can transfer content by XML or JSON to a client.

It is ok if the CMS can also manage HTML websites, but the priority is on the data transfer over a web service.

Which is the best CMS to use here? I want to avoid spending endless hours learning all the big CMS systems just to find out that they don't support this feature or that it's badly integrated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the one I use: http://www.dialogs.com we're just wrapping up an app for a major TV show
(can't say which). Spitting out data (from a database store) in json format is dead simple and you can also add regular html pages if you need and integrate the data from the app. Cost is $500 and consulting is available.

Answer (score 0):

I regularly use SDL Tridion. It has excellent support for your scenario, with the ability to publish data to content delivery systems that can serve it for mobile apps as an OData service (so either Atom or JSON).